# Is there any way to store values in OPA

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have a usecase to do like, if a variable is already defined then return that value else invoke a rest endpoint to get the variable.

```
get_value = value {
   data.value
   value
}else = value {
    value := <> #invoke rest
}
```

I will be running OPA as a server and my expectation is like, in the first invokation it will go to the else block then to the first block for rest of the calls. Could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to the in-memory store from a policy, no. Except for that though, your code looks fine, and I'd say it's a pretty common pattern to first check for the existence of a value in `data` before fetching it via `http.send`. One thing to note though is that you may use caching on the `http.send` call, which would effectively do the same thing you're after:

```
value := http.send({
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "method": "get",
    
    # Cached for one hour
    "force_cache": true,
    "force_cache_duration": 3600
})
```

If the server responds with caching headers, you won't even need to use `force_cache` but can simply say `cache: true` and the `http.send` client will cache according to what the server suggests.